# adding keys to a sequence of vectors in a vector and converting them to hash-maps

Tags: clojure, lisp

Given

```
[["foo" "bar" 2] ["biz" "baf" 3]]
```

how do I get

```
[{:a "foo" :b "bar" :num 2} {:a "biz" :b "baf" :num 3}]?
```

In reality my vector has hundreds of vectors that need to have keys added and be converted to hash-maps.

Comment: something like this: `(mapv (partial zipmap [:a :b :num]) [["foo" "bar" 2]["biz" "baf" 3]])`

Comment: Thanks for this... did the trick!

I would have accepted this as the answer but it's a comment do I don't think I can.

Answer (score 1):

What leetwinski said, or:

```
(def input [["foo" "bar" 2]["biz" "baf" 3]])

(mapv (fn [[a b num]]
        {:a a
         :b b
         :num num}) input)
```

If you need to convert a lot of data, maybe `mapv` is not the best option because it will keep the whole vector in memory at once. Normal `map` which creates a lazy seq, or a transducer might be better in that case.

Comment: Great, thanks... the memory aspect is definitely good to keep in mind!

Comment: As for me I find this variant to be better than zipmap, because it is more refactoring-friendly and readable

Comment: A minor detail: this way is also more performant than zipmap, but we're talking about 22 vs 220 ns so not likely to be noticed.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution:

```
(defn vectors->maps 
 "takes a vector of vectors containing values and a vector of keys
  and returns a vector of maps such that each value at index n in the value 
  vector is paired with each key at index n in the keys vector
  ex: (vectors->maps [["foo" "bar" 2] ["biz" "baf" 3]], [:a :b :num]) 
         => [{:a "foo", :b "bar", :num 2} {:a "biz", :b "baf", :num 3}]"
  [vectors keys] 
 (mapv (partial zipmap keys) vectors))
```

Exercise for the reader: writing a spec for this function and generating tests for it to ferret out any edge cases